# Mongoose functions after exec()

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

How can run functions like sort and other functions after exec() in mongoose.

I tried to find all documents and populate some fields after that I executed how can I run other functions after I executed in mongoose

Comment: What exactly do you need to do? Is there a reason for wanting to call `sort` after `exec`? Give us an example of how your schema and query look like, and explain the problem that you wish to solve.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Country.find(search).sort(sort).exec((err, result) => {
            if (err) return res.send(err);
            if (result.length != 0) {
                return res.send(result, 'Country list');
            } else {
                return res.send({}, 'No countries', 400);
            }
        })
```

hope this is what your looking for and find it usefull